# Is it possible to use more than one same loader in one activity?

Tags: android, loader, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to load some data from more than one file that have the same structure. I have built a loader that can load data from one file, but now I don't know how to use the loader to load all these files' data one by one, and then add all these data to one list. Is it possible to use only one loader in for(){} sententce?

Answer (score 0):

If your `for` statement can a) recognize it's reached the end of its input, b) switch over to the new input source, then yes, a single loop can do this.

That being said, you would be making code which is needlessly difficult to maintain and difficult to scale (for example, to add a 3rd input source). You would be better off with one piece of code to iterate through your input sources and when a new source is to be processed, hands the open descriptor over to a new function to receive data from that source.